# Get the row and column number of query from Fillo executeUpdate method

Tags: xlsx

When using fillo library, I am able to get the job done by updating, inserting the values to the spread sheet. But I want to know the row and column number of the row the query has acted upon ? Any help greatly appreciated

As of now if you use fillo, you will not get the row and column number the select or update query worked on. I want to know which row and column number the update has been made.

Comment: Can you add more details? Where is the code? Description of the problem will not help you get a solution.what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Thanks ! I have udpated few more lines